# Create regex phone number validating all number except one format

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex which authorized all phone number in the format :

```
0nxxxxxxxx with n between 1-9 and 8 times x between 0-9
```

My regex is

```
0[1-9][0-9]{8}
```

Now, I want to exclude the number which begin by 0590xxxxxx.
So, for example

```
0123456789 => true
...        => true
0590123456 => false
```

How can I modify my regex to do this ?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add negative lookahead `(?!0590)` before your pattern:

```
(?!0590)0[1-9][0-9]{8}
```

See [RegexStorm Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F!0590)0%5B1-9%5D%5B0-9%5D%7B8%7D&i=0123456789%0D%0A0590123456&o=m)

Improvements:

- I suggest you to use start `^` and end `$` anchors if you want to avoid matches like `abc0123456789abc` or use word boundaries `\b`
- you can replace `[0-9]` with `\d`

Improved regex:

```
^(?!0590)0[1-9]\d{8}$
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the negative lookahead. I need the ^ and $ anchors like you suggest. The problem is when I add them to the pattern, it never matches with a correct input [RegexStormDemo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%3f!0590)0%5b1-9%5d%5b0-9%5d%7b8%7d%24&i=0123456789%0d%0a0590123456&o=m)

Comment: Yes.. something is wrong.. but it will work.. checked with another [online tester](http://fiddle.re/rqnh26) :)

Comment: Indeed, it works, it's exactly what I needed. Thanks